# How to create a folder in the repository in GitHub?

Tags: github, repository

I'm a new user in GitHub and I need to create a folder in the repository in my Github account to classify codes. But I don't know how I can do it.

I tried to create a folder but I couldn't. I couldn't find appropriate options to do that. After creating a new repository, what can i do before "creating a new file" in that repository?

Comment: See [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/315911/354577)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the same thing!  I'm sure there is a better way to do it, but my solution was to go to the "upload files" section and just upload an empty folder (or even one that already has the files you want in it).